# Teradata 15 : Failure 5619 Role nesting exceeded single-level

Tags: teradata

I am using Teradata 15.  In Active Directory, We have a policy to assign a universal group, which has people, to a local group, where permissions are assigned. So I create two Teradata roles to mimic this structure.

I granted one role to another role:

```
grant role_1 to role_2;
```

but I got the following error.

```
*** Failure 5619 Role nesting exceeded single-level.
```

I am wondering if I need to create special type of roles to identify a parent and a child relationship first?

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Teradata only allows one level of role nesting, there's no workaround.

Either `role_2` or is already granted to another role or `role_1` has been granted another role.

```
role_a -- top level
   | 
role_b -- GRANT role_b TO role_a; this is ok, 1st nested level
   | 
role_c -- GRANT role_c T1O role_b; this will fail, 2nd nested level
```